# Efficiently compute an SHA-256 message digest from an image pixel stream in python

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

Looking to create a message digest of the image pixel stream of a variety of image types (TIFF, BMP, CR2, NEF, GIF, JPG). This will be used as a unique identifier for an image, and should remain persistent even if the file metadata changes.

I’ve explored the ImageMagick “identify” tool to do exactly this, however it is very slow for large images (~16 seconds for an 80mb NEF file). I suspect this is because it uncompresses the image before computing the message digest.

Perhaps there is a general way to compute the message digest without uncompressing the image?

Comment: Do you need the `SHA-256` be calculated from the whole image?

Comment: No, a portion of the image would be sufficient.

Comment: NEFs are Nikon raw camera files: they are a TIFF container with the actual pixels hidden in tags, and a preview as the image data. ImageMagick will have to shell out to dcraw to generate the RGB data, and that will take ages (as you say). You could call libtiff directly, read out an undocumented tag, and calculate a hash from that, I guess. You could also load as a TIFF and just use the camera preview.

Comment: Though I wouldn't be surprised if many of the details of which TIFF tags you needed to read for a NEF varied between Nikon camera models. It's a manufacturer's format and is undocumented and unsupported (except for basic read) by everyone else. I think a simple hash of the whole file would probably be sufficient.